# SQL Server: creating table variable, error in primary key constraint definition

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, indexing

I'm trying to create a table variable with primary key. What is the difference between these two statements? Why the first one does not work?

```
--This does not work
declare @tabvar table (
    rowid int identity(1, 1) not null,
    var1 int null,
        constraint PK_tabvar_rowid primary key clustered (rowid)
)

--This works
declare @tabvar1 table (
    rowid int identity(1, 1) not null primary key clustered,
    var1 int null
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this behavior is well documented in *BOL*. Look at the syntax definitions for [DECLARE TABLE Variable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188927.aspx) vs [CREATE TABLE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174979.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

When you create a table like:

```
CREATE TABLE tabvar (
rowid int identity(1, 1) not null,
var1 int null
   , constraint PK_tabvar_rowid primary key clustered (rowid))
```

you create a separate SQL object called PK_tabvar_rowid.

This method is preferred for permanent tables as above, because you specifically name the constraint and it exists independently from the table object.

You CAN use the form:

```
 CREATE TABLE tabvar (
rowid int identity(1, 1) not null primary key,
var1 int null)
```

but this creates a randomly named constraint, which makes future management more difficult.

For table variables (which are transient) - you CANNOT have an independent constraint - so you MUST use the inline primary key definition.

Answer (score 1):

There are differences in the syntax between the [CREATE TABLE (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174979.aspx) and [DECLARE @local_variable (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188927.aspx) used in creating table variables. You can not use the syntax of the first statement to create a variable table.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax you're using is for [`CREATE TABLE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174979.aspx), not table variables.

```
CREATE TABLE tabvar (
    rowid int identity(1, 1) not null,
    var1 int null
       , constraint PK_tabvar_rowid primary key clustered (rowid)
)
```

The above works fine, as expected. However if you look at the syntax for [declaring table variables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175010.aspx) you'll see what you can and can't do:

```
declare @tabvar table (
    rowid int identity(1, 1) not null,
    var1 int null,
       primary key (rowid)
)
```